# quick path interconnect vs AXI

Tags: interconnect, latency

I want to know the performance difference between AXI and Intel's quick path interconnect which has been replaced by Ultra path interconnect(interms of latency). This is for very low latency(25 microseconds per sample) motion controller application.

Thanks in advance!
Nivetha